# Restart server every day

Tags: windows-server-2008

How can I make my windows server 2008 to Restart itself everyday at midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [task scheduler](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Working-Windows-Server-2008-Task-Scheduler-Part1.html) with the following command:

```
shutdown -r -f
```